# REST API - suddenly returning 401 error

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Starting this morning, we began receiving a 401 error when sending a request. Nothing we know has changed on our end

```
{
  "message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
  "parameters": {
    "resources": "Magento_Sales::sales"
  }
}
```

This was previously working with no issues. Here is the sample request:

```
curl -X GET -k -H 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_nonce="tNmhe", oauth_timestamp="1560297878", oauth_consumer_key="key_here", oauth_token="token_here", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="sig_here"' -i 'https://domain/rest/V1/orders/7586/'
```